# modifiy the result value of $cond even more in mongoose aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I implement an aggregation on my orders collection, where I calculate a driverDebt field like this,

```
 driverDebt: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: ["$status", ["driverHasPaid", "paid"]],
          },
          0,
          "$driverDebt",
        ],
      },
    },
```

what I want to do is to subtract another value from "$driverDebt" if the condition I want is met, something like this for example (ik its wrong) :

```
driverDebt: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: ["$status", ["driverHasPaid", "paid"]],
          },
          0,
           $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$deliveryFeeCollected", "no"] }, $subtract: ["$driverDebt", "$deliveryPrice"], "$driverDebt"] 
         },,
        ],
      },
    },
```

so basically I want to check if deliveryFee is not collected, deduct the price equivalent to the deliveryPrice from the driverDebt. I could run a loop on the aggregation result and do the math there, but I want to implement it in the aggregation. Hope its clear enough to understand.
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Query
I am not sure you want this but this does :

```js
if("$status" in ["driverHasPaid", "paid"]) driverDept=$driverDept
else if("$deliveryFeeCollected"="no") driverDept= "$driverDept"-"$deliveryPrice"
else driverDept = "$driverDept";
```

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"driverDept": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$in": ["$status", ["driverHasPaid", "paid"]]}, "$driverDept",
        {"$cond": 
          [{"$eq": ["$deliveryFeeCollected", "no"]},
           {"$subtract": ["$driverDebt", "$deliveryPrice"]},
           "$driverDept"]}]}}}])
```

If this isn't want you need, if you give us like pseudocode it will help alot.

Comment: thanks for your answer , my problem was I didnt know you can use other operators as children of $cond, so I just replaced your part of the $cond and modified it a little. so yep that was my issue.